# Javascript get Selected Index from Many Selection Lists

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create categories of government websites where the user can click from a selection list and they will be directed to that location. the problem is I can't get the selectedIndex form this many selection lists or maybe I messed something up elsewhere. The option values contain the links. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/By4v4/) link to play with.

HTML

```
<p>Select a site from one of the drop-down lists below.</p>
<table>
   <tr><td>Executive Branch</td>
       <td><select name="executive" id="executive" class="optionLinks">
           <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
           <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov">The White House</option>
           <option value="http://www.usda.gov">Department of Agriculture</option>
           <option value="http://www.doc.gov">Department of Commerce</option>
           <option value="http://www.defenselink.mil">Department of Defense</option>
           <option value="http://www.ed.gov">Department of Education</option>
           <option value="http://www.energy.gov">Department of Energy</option>
           <option value="http://www.os.dhhs.gov">Department of Health and Human Services</option>
           <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov/homeland">Department of Homeland Security</option>
           <option value="http://www.hud.gov">Department of Housing and Urban Development</option>
           <option value="http://www.doi.gov">Department of the Interior</option>
           <option value="http://www.usdoj.gov">Department of Justice</option>
           <option value="http://www.dol.gov">Department of Labor</option>
           <option value="http://www.state.gov">Department of State</option>
           <option value="http://www.ustreas.gov">Department of the Treasury</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>Legislative Branch</td>
       <td><select name="legislative" id="legislative" class="optionLinks">
           <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
           <option value="http://www.house.gov">House Web Site</option>
           <option value="http://www.house.gov/house/MemberWWW.shtml">Representatives' Web Sites</option>
           <option value="http://clerk.house.gov/">Clerk of the House</option>
           <option value="http://www.gpoaccess.gov/cdirectory/index.html">Congressional Directory</option>
           <option value="http://www.senate.gov">Senate Web Site</option>
           <option value="http://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm">Senators' Web Sites</option>
           <option value="http://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/generic/Senate_Historical_Office.htm">Senate Historic Office</option>
           <option value="http://www.cq.com">Congressional Quarterly</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/">Library of Congress</option>
           <option value="http://www.gao.gov/">Government Accountability Office</option>
           <option value="http://www.cbo.gov/">Congressional Budget Office</option>
           <option value="http://www.gpoaccess.gov/">Government Printing Office</option>
           <option value="http://thomas.loc.gov/home/legbranch/otherleg.html#govpub">Government Records and Publications</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>Judicial Branch</td>
       <td><select name="judicial" id="judicial" class="optionLinks">
           <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
           <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov">U.S. Courts</option>
           <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov/supremecourt.html">U.S. Supreme Court</option>
           <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov/courtsofappeals.html">U.S. Courts of Appeals</option>
           <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov/districtcourts.html">U.S. District Courts</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>State Governments</td>
       <td><select name="state" id="state" class="optionLinks">
           <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
           <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/index.cfm">State and Local Government on the Net</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/al-gov.html">Alabama</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ak-gov.html">Alaska</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/az-gov.html">Arizona</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ar-gov.html">Arkansas</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ca-gov.html">California</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/co-gov.html">Colorado</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ct-gov.html">Connecticut</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/de-gov.html">Delaware</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/dc-gov.html">District of Columbia</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/fl-gov.html">Florida</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ga-gov.html">Georgia</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/hi-gov.html">Hawaii</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/id-gov.html">Idaho</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/il-gov.html">Illinois</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/in-gov.html">Indiana</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ia-gov.html">Iowa</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ks-gov.html">Kansas</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ky-gov.html">Kentucky</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/la-gov.html">Louisana</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/me-gov.html">Maine</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/md-gov.html">Maryland</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ma-gov.html">Massachusetts</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/mi-gov.html">Michigan</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/mn-gov.html">Minnesota</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ms-gov.html">Mississippi</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/mo-gov.html">Missouri</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/mn-gov.html">Montana</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ne-gov.html">Nebraska</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nv-gov.html">Nevada</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nh-gov.html">New Hampshire</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nj-gov.html">New Jersey</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nm-gov.html">New Mexico</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ny-gov.html">New York</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nc-gov.html">North Carolina</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/nd-gov.html">North Dakota</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/oh-gov.html">Ohio</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ok-gov.html">Oklahoma</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/or-gov.html">Oregon</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/pa-gov.html">Pennsylvania</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ri-gov.html">Rhode Island</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/sc-gov.html">South Carolina</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/sd-gov.html">South Dakota</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/tn-gov.html">Tennessee</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/tx-gov.html">Texas</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/ut-gov.html">Utah</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/vt-gov.html">Vermont</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/va-gov.html">Virginia</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/wa-gov.html">Washington</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/wv-gov.html">West Virginia</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/wi-gov.html">Wisconsin</option>
           <option value="http://www.loc.gov/global/state/wy-gov.html">Wyoming</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>​
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for(var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++)
        allSelect[i].addEventListener('onchange', loadLink());
}

function loadLink()
{
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for(var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++)
        if(allSelect[i].selectedIndex > 0)
            alert(allSelect[i].options[selectedIndex].value);
}​
```

Comment: Using `onchange` with select elements isn't a good strategy. Using keyboard navigation, some browsers will dispatch a change event each time a different option is focused and before it is selected. So users are re–directed as soon as they try to navigate to the next or previous option, regardless if that's the one they wanted to select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `addEventListener` you need to pass a reference to a function, but you were *calling* the function by including parentheses after it. Also when using `addEventListener` the event is `'change'`, not `'onchange'` (drop the "on" from all events for use with `addEventListener`). So:

```
allSelect[i].addEventListener('onchange', loadLink());    // is NOT correct
allSelect[i].addEventListener('change', loadLink);        // is correct
```

Also in this line of your second function:

```
alert(allSelect[i].options[selectedIndex].value);
```

You were using a variable `selectedIndex` that isn't defined. That line should've been:

```
alert(allSelect[i].options[allSelect[i].selectedIndex].value);
```

Also in your fiddle you weren't actually calling `init()`.

Here's a "working" version:

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for(var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++)
        allSelect[i].addEventListener('change', loadLink, false);    
}

function loadLink()
{
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    for(var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++)
        if(allSelect[i].selectedIndex > 0)
            alert(allSelect[i].options[allSelect[i].selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/By4v4/5/

Do you really want to loop through *all* select elements every time one of them changes? You can do this to get the value of the one that changed:

```
function loadLink()
{
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/By4v4/12/

Comment: Thank you! I've wondered what the difference was between `function()` and `function` when adding events.

Comment: You're welcome. `someFunc()` _calls_ the function, but `someFunc` is a _reference_ to the function. Note that you already did it correctly with `window.onload = init;`. Also, I updated my answer to mention that you don't need to loop through all the selects to get the value of the one that changed, because within the event handler `this` is a reference to the element in question. (I forgot to mention that initially because I was focused on correcting the things that were stopping your code working as it was.)

Answer (score 1):

you aren't invoking the function `init()` and also assign events like the example in jsfiddle ,but check the below example

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/By4v4/11/)